# How to identify Ideal Size for a Application host C drive?

Tags: windows, disk

I want to make sure that the Application Drive is having enough space , for that i wanted to understand the Ideal Size for the  Drive where i am hosting the application.  Can somebody help me find the ideal size of the drive -

**Application Size - 24 GB
Having log Data of - 14 GB- 20 GB
Other Files - 10 GB.**

For the Above specification , what should be ideal size of the drive.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your server environment? Is the operating system (assuming a Windows Server) also on the same drive, is the application data most likely to grow, does the app frequently write large chunks to the drive, how much RAM is available (impacts the pagefile size and the available space on the drive) and more...

Comment: @Rob Vermeulen , Thanks , Details as below -Its a Windows Server .The Operating System is not on the same drive. Yes It may increase to few GB's. It writes more than 3 to 4 GB of data on the Drive daily. Which we usually remove after a month. It's a Clustered environment and the specification here is for one of the cluster instance.

Comment: Then I would go for a size that is at least 10% larger than the highest amount of storage you would need. In case the OS is on the same drive, then a surplus of 25%. would be preferable.